# How to whitelist msiexec called from an app whitelisted via RunAsInvoker

Tags: windows, uac, windows-installer, whitelist

I whitelisted a legacy app via the `RunAsInvoker` registry key, which works fine.
However, when the user selects the repair option offered by the app, the whitelisted app actually executes `msiexec /fa installer.msi`, which requires admin rights.
What would be the best option to whitelist `msiexec` when called from another app?

Comment: It's not something that should ever be done, as it's a massive security risk. Installers, including `MSIexec`, require Admin privs when installing software outside of `%UserProfile%`, so a better solution would be installing this specific application to either `%AppData%` or `%LocalAppData%`; doing so will not require Admin privs when it needs to be updated/repaired by the user _(this is a per-user install)_

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Maybe I should have described the problem more clearly. The app that I whitelisted via `RunAsInvoker` is a dedicated repair utility that allows the user to repair a software suite installed in `%ProgramData%`. It offers the user several repair options. One of the options actually runs `msiexec /fa installer.msi`. I tried installing both the repair utility and the program suite in `%AppData%`, however, it didn't make a difference. I'm still getting the UAC dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

To force a program that requires elevation to run without elevation, use this command:

```
cmd.exe /c "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker && msiexec /fa installer.msi"
```

However, the installer might in this case not be able to do its job if it
requires access to admin-only folders.

An alternative is to use the Nirsoft tool
[RunWithoutElevation](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_without_elevation.html)
with a command like:

```
RunWithoutElevation.exe msiexec /fa installer.msi
```

The values for `__COMPAT_LAYER` are:

- **RunAsInvoker**: The application should run with the same privileges and
  user rights as the parent process.
- **RunAsHighest**: The application should run with the highest Windows privileges
  and user rights the current user can obtain, but not necessarily require the user
  to be an administrator.
- **RunAsAdmin**: The application should run only for administrators,
  must be launched with a full administrator access token, and will not run correctly
  in a standard user context.